# Histogram with divided bars

Tags: histograms

I have file with the flux as a function of time given as Modified Julian Day (MJD). Now I need to make a histogram of the all fluxes. I also need put into each bar information about times when given flux point occured. The main idea is to divide each bar into $n$ pieces ($n$ is the number of repetitions of a given flux value) and each piece should have a color depending on time (color bar). Is there any option to do this easily in Mathematica? I have tried `StackedBarChart` option, but with no results on this moment. Below is part of my code in Mathematica, but at this moment I'm able to get only simple histogram (beginner level).

```
mydata = Import["MJD_Flux_HR.dat", {"Data"}];
time = mydata[[All, 1]];
Rate = mydata[[All, 2]];

Histogram[
  Log[Rate], 50, 
  ChartElementFunction -> "FadingRectangle", 
  ChartStyle -> Orange, 
  GridLines -> {None, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100}}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed],  
  AxesLabel -> {log[Flux], N}]
```

I will be very grateful for any tip or for a link if a similar problem was already resolved.

#### Edit

```
MJD                      Flux

5.629479115953703877e+04 1.968644999999999978e+00
5.629479810398148402e+04 2.117290000000000116e+00
5.629493004842592927e+04 2.360141000000000044e+00
5.629493699287037452e+04 2.449203999999999937e+00
5.629494393731481978e+04 2.565354000000000134e+00
5.629495782620370301e+04 3.023746000000000045e+00
5.630207443500000227e+04 1.597088999999999981e+00
...
5.638481801138888841e+04 1.853978000000000037e+01
5.638482495583332638e+04 1.915412999999999855e+01
5.638483190027777164e+04 1.835502999999999929e+01
...
```

Comment: Share a sample from your data so we can better understand what you are working with. If you can find an example of a plot in the style you want, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 4):

Is this along the lines of what you have in mind?

```
data = RandomReal[{10, 100}, {10, 4}];

BarChart[
 data,
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked"
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How to achieve this will strongly depend on the structure of your data though. It would be best if you could share some.

Answer (score 4):

my interpretation:

```
data = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, Join[
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 1], 100] ,
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[11, 1], 100] ]];

hbins = HistogramList[data[[All, 2]]][[1]];
bw = -Subtract @@ hbins[[1 ;; 2]];
bins = Interval[#] & /@ Partition[hbins, 2, 1];
bindata = 
  Function[{bin}, Select[data, IntervalMemberQ[bin, #[[2]]] &]] /@ 
   bins;
trange = MinMax@data[[All, 1]];
bar[x_, w_, colors_] := 
 Graphics[ {#[[1]], Rectangle[Sequence @@ #[[2]]]} & /@
   MapIndexed[ {#, {{x - w/2, First@#2 - 1}, {x + w/2, First@#2}}} &, 
    colors ]]
Show[MapThread[ 
  bar[#1, .7 bw, 
    Hue[Rescale[#, trange, {0, 2/3}]] & /@ #2[[All, 1]]] &,
  {Mean /@ Partition[hbins, 2, 1], bindata}], Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Edit, oh I knew there was a simpler way:

```
BarChart[HistogramList[data][[2]] // Transpose, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image]